# "Talking to someone is nice." or "It is nice to talk to someone." but "It was nice, talking to you." Why?

Tags: formality, writing, speech, gerund-vs-infinitive, general-vs-specific

General statement:

a.  Talking to someone is nice. (verb as subject in front position = gerund)

or

b.  It is nice to talk to someone. (verb as subject after dummy subject 'it' = full infinitive)

Specific situation:

It was nice, talking to you? (**Why?** Is it a mix of a. and b.?)

Comment: All three are correct. It just depends what you want to say. 'Nice' is a heavily overworked and inexpressive word.

Comment: Or "talking to you was nice" or "it was nice to talk to you".

Comment: As a side note I wouldn't use a comma there, and I don't think I ever saw anyone else do that.

Comment: This is a grammatical point I stumbled upon in 'Ideas and Issues, Intermediate' by Olivia Johnson and Mark Farrel, Chancerel International Publishers Ltd, 2000, page 56, Key Language, which had the expample sentences "Making new friends can be difficult." (quote: in writing, we usually put the gerund at the beginning) to be turned into "It can be difficult, making new friends." WITH a comma (quote: this [the gerund at the end of the sentence] often happens in speech).

Answer (score 1):

> Talking to someone is nice

and

> It is nice to talk to someone

Have the same meaning. They merely reflect the use of the infinitive (a Teutonic structure) versus the use of the gerunditive (a feature from French).

In both cases, they express as a generality that it is pleasant to engage in conversation.

---

The sentence:

> It was nice talking to you.

This sentence is a way of thanking someone for having conversed with you.

You can equally say

> It was nice to talk to you.

These sentences are in the past tense and express (ostensibly) a judgment about a previously held conversation. Conversely, the other sentences being in the present tense express more generally that conversation is nice.

Answer (score 0):

*Generally*, the thing you want to emphasize should come first in the statement.

To emphasize the action of talking, you would say "Talking to you was nice". And to emphasize the nice feeling, you would say "It was nice to talk to you".

Answer (score 0):

"It was nice talking to you" seems ambiguous to me. Does it mean that it no longer is nice talking to you or "Thank you for the conversation"?. Adding the comma makes it clear that it is the latter.

Answer (score -1):

It might seem that there is a mix of a. and b. in the sentence "It was nice, talking to you.", but I don't think there is.

The sentence is spoken English, rather informal. So, another rule, which applies here, is that continuous verb forms feel less formal than simple ones, e.g. "I am feeling cold." versus "I feel cold."; "I was thinking…" versus "I thought…" etc.

So I would argue that "It was nice, talking to you." is in fact the sentence "It was nice to be talking to you." (type b.) with 'to be' dropped and replaced by a comma.

This is a grammatical point I stumbled upon in 'Ideas and Issues, Intermediate' by Olivia Johnson and Mark Farrel, Chancerel International Publishers Ltd, 2000, page 56, Key Language, which had the expample sentences "Making new friends can be difficult." (quote: in writing, we usually put the gerund at the beginning) to be turned into "It can be difficult, making new friends." WITH a comma (quote: this [the gerund at the end of the sentence] often happens in speech).

Comment: *nice to be talking to you* would have to be *nice to have been talking to you* (to place it in the past test).

Comment: I agree, but the difference formal–informal remains: nice to have talked to you (Perfect Simple Infinitive) versus to have been talking to you (Perfect Continuous Infinitive)…